# Javascript - how do i check if the movie is finished? while using jQuery and other third party libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have some third party library and jQuery now using Javascript i need to detect if any video is playing and ended as event listener.

I tried following but its not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(InitialiseDocReadyScripts()) {
        console.log('Initialised Document Ready Scripts Successfully');
    } else {
        console.log('Failed to Initialise Document Ready Scripts');
    }

  var play_video = document.getElementById('mediaplayer');
  play_video.onended = function(e) {
    console.log('>>> Playing finished: ', e);
  };

});
```

Comment: _"some third party library"_, could you elaborate? Is it public so we can look at the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that the current playtime is `==` to the length of the video.

```
 play_video.onended = function(e) {
    if(this.currentTime == this.duration) {
        console.log('video end');
    }
 };
```

`currentTime` and `duration` are properties of html5 video: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp